# localhost srv record forwarding in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind, srv-record

I want to each url to be forwarded to in my localmachine. For example:

```
sub1.domain.com ---> http://localhost:1111
sub2.domain.com ---> http://localhost:2222
sub3.domain.com ---> http://localhost:3333
```

How do I add SRV records to achieve this? I tried bind9 documents
and never got to figure out. Any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, HTTP clients no nothing about SRV records. You will need to use some sort of reverse proxy to accomplish this.